# Related items - make two way correlation between records

Tags: mysql, database-design, data-modeling

I'm using a MySql database, where I have a table called `books`.

I would like to implement a system by which the user can relate two items, so that when viewing one, it appears a link to the other.

My problem is that I would like to do so in a way that when `book1` (`id==1`) is linked to `book2` (`id==2`), also `book2` is linked to `book1`, and viceversa.

The way I was thinking to do so was to make a new table, called `relations` and to have at least two cols `col1` and `col2`, in which I save the ids of all related items.
For example, the row for `book1` and `book2` would look like this:

```
  —————————————————
 |  COL1  |  COL2  |
  —————————————————
1|   1    |   2    |
  —————————————————
```

So when viewing `book1` I would `SELECT * FROM 'relations' WHERE COL1 = '1' OR COL2 = '1'`

I guess that in this way it should work, but I was wondering if there is a better/more efficient way of dealing with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "or" - clause is a killer for index-usages. I would say if your relation is symmetric just add both pairs into the table - so 1-2 and 2-1.

It doubles the space needed, but - that's SQL. ;-)

Edit
To clarify "kills index": when you have an index on col1, the request

```
select col2 from correlation_table where col1 = 12
```

is very quick, whereas the statement

```
select col1, col2 from correlation_table where col1 = 12 or col2 = 12
```

is slow and as soon as you have many relations you would need an index on col1 and one on col2 and you would have to break the query into

```
    select col1, col2 from correlation_table where col1 = 12
  union
    select col1, col2 from correlation_table where col2 = 12
```

Comment: What you mean by "killer for index-usages"? Would it make any difference if I had a third column ad index (incremental id)? I was thinking to have it anyways...

Comment: The MySQL-Query-Optimizer can use one index per table. If you query "where col1 = 12 or col2 = 12" it can't use an index.

A third column would not change that, but a unique id is a good idea for some reasons.

I would better try to avoid col1 = '1' when col1 is numeric, col1 = 1 should do better.